# testNG suite tag timestamp differs with test-method timestamp in testng-results.xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium, appium-android

I am generating an Excel report to capture the start time and the end time of the suite execution, wherein framework reads the data from testng-results.xml, however, I noticed the difference in the started-at time and finished-at time at the suite level and method level. My framework reads the time at the suite level and the time is not I expect it to be. I am expecting the suite-time to be the same as the method level time.

```
<suite name="Suite" duration-ms="1543927" started-at="2018-03-15T05:53:39Z" finished-at="2018-03-15T06:19:23Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="Regression_test" duration-ms="1543927" started-at="2018-03-15T05:53:39Z" finished-at="2018-03-15T06:19:23Z">
        <class name="com.mpos.android.tests.CnC_TC_08">
            <test-method status="PASS" signature="_init()[pri:0, instance:com.mpos.android.tests.CnC_TC_08@627551fb]" name="_init" is-config="true" duration-ms="2" started-at="2018-03-15T11:31:27Z" finished-at="2018-03-15T11:31:27Z">
                <reporter-output>
                </reporter-output>
            </test-method> <!-- _init -->
```

Here is the Excel report generated using the above code snippet:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<suite>` tag and the `<test-method>` tag *timestamp* of `started-at` property says it all.

- The `started-at` timeatamp in `<suite>` tag mentions **2018-03-15T05:53:39Z**
- The `started-at` timeatamp in `<test-method>` tag mentions **2018-03-15T11:31:27Z**
- So the time difference is of **5 hours, 37 minutes and 48 seconds**

### Analysis

This indicates that :

- The `started-at` timeatamp in `<suite>` tag which mentions **2018-03-15T05:53:39Z** is of **GMT**
- The `started-at` timeatamp in `<test-method>` tag which mentions **2018-03-15T11:31:27Z** is of (possibly) **IST (Indian Standard Time)**

### Solution

A quick solution will be to upgrade your **TestNG** version to the latest **GA v6.14.2** where the *timestamps* where both the timestamps will be of **GMT**.

- An example of a currently execution is as follows :

  ```
  <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" ignored="0" total="1" passed="1">
    <reporter-output>
    </reporter-output>
    <suite name="Default suite" duration-ms="13267" started-at="2018-03-17T10:50:04Z" finished-at="2018-03-17T10:50:17Z">
      <groups>
      </groups>
      <test name="Default test" duration-ms="13267" started-at="2018-03-17T10:50:04Z" finished-at="2018-03-17T10:50:17Z">
        <class name="Config_property_demo.Index">
      <test-method status="PASS" signature="handling_multiple_windows()[pri:1, instance:Config_property_demo.Index@2bbf4b8b]" name="handling_multiple_windows" duration-ms="13236" started-at="2018-03-17T10:50:04Z" finished-at="2018-03-17T10:50:17Z">
        <reporter-output>
        </reporter-output>
      </test-method> <!-- handling_multiple_windows -->
        </class> <!-- Config_property_demo.Index -->
      </test> <!-- Default test -->
    </suite> <!-- Default suite -->
  </testng-results>
  ```
- Though my system *timestamp* (apprx) at **2018-03-17T16:50:04Z** but `<suite>` tag and `<test-method>` tag both shows **2018-03-17T10:50:04Z**